# Laravel 5.8: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I have added this code to my Controller:

```
public function denyRequest($id)
    {
        $findRequest = WithdrawWallet::find($id);
        $findRequest->status = 'cancelled';
        $findRequest->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

And here is route for this:

```
Route::get('{id}','Wallet\WalletController@denyRequest')->name('denyRequest');
```

Now I get this error:

> **ErrorException** (E_WARNING) Creating default object from empty value

Which is referring to this:

[image]

So what's going really wrong here? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Check if your collection `$findRequest` is not empty first then try to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search for existing Withdraw Wallet with an id that doesnt exist, it will return null. and since you assign `'cancelled'` as an object attribute on the variable, php will convert `$findRequest` to a default object (StdObject::class) to be able to assign the attribute to it.

One simple solution would be to use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()` wich will trigger an exception when the id doesnt exist in your DataBase and return a 404 response on the request.

```
$findRequest = WithdrawWallet::findOrFail($id);
$findRequest->status = 'cancelled';
$findRequest->save();

return redirect()->back();
```

another suggestion (if you have soft delete on on the model and the id exists in the database) is to use withTrashed()

```
$findRequest = WithdrawWallet::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$findRequest->status = 'cancelled';
$findRequest->save();

return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `find` with `findOrFail`:

```
$findRequest = WithdrawWallet::findOrFail($id);
```